# UITableView does not refresh after returning from its child view

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I'm reading the Big Nerd Ranch's book and I have written a little app using `UITableView`. Let the `UITableView` shows the items in the inventory. When `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, it enters a subview and you can edit the properties of item here, which is `detailViewController`. Afterwards you can go back to `UITableView` via the navigation controller's back button.

However it doesn't refresh after pressing back button at first. You have to go to a `detailViewController` and come back to see the change, it's not important whether it is same item.

Navigation goes like: `ItemsViewController > DetailViewController`

ItemsViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
           forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    UIView * header = self.headerView;
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:header];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    //  Clear first responder
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    //  Save "changes" to the item
    BNRItem * item = self.item;
    item.itemName = self.nameField.text;
    item.serialNumber = self.serialNumberField.text;
    item.valueInDollars = [self.valueField.text intValue];
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the values in `viewWillDisappear:` method in `DetailViewController`. `viewWillAppear:` method of `ItemsViewController` executes before `viewDidDisappear:` of `DetailViewController`, therefore your `BNRItem` changes after the table is refreshed.